# Optimize 950k+ lookups in pandas dataframe

Tags: python

I'm currently working on a project where I'm dealing with somewhat large data sets. I have a dataframe `transactions` and another `users`.

Iterating through the transactions dataframe is no problem. I used `timeit` and it takes just under a minute to do so. My second dataframe `users` has 1,000 rows. Both of these dataframes have a column `email`. Essentially what i'm trying to do is get the `userId` in the row in `users` that matches the `email` in each `transactions` row. My current approach looks like this:

```
for row in transactions.itertuples():
    userId = users[users['email'] == getattr(row, 'email')]['userId'].values[0]
```

This simple lookup works, however it's too slow for my use case. I kept it running for over an hour and it still wasn't finished running. I'm wondering if there's potentially a faster way to do this lookup (maybe get the runtime down to minutes instead of hours)?

Appreciate any help in advance!

Comment: Hey, welcome to Code Review! Please add some more code, as we cannot review this without the context. Please also add some example input data (and example output), as this makes it easier to check if proposed changes do not change the intention of your code.

Comment: Also, can there be more than one user with the same email?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrame#merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-or-named-series-joining-merging).

```
df = transactions.merge(users, on="email")
```